# OSError: stream operation not supported ujson_load

Tags: python, json, ota, oserror

I get following error in my python code:

```
  File "main.py", line 55, in <module>
  File "/flash/lib/OTA.py", line 54, in update
  File "/flash/lib/OTA.py", line 49, in get_update_manifest
OSError: stream operation not supported
```

Code that makes problems:

```
    def get_update_manifest(self):
        print(self.get_current_version())
        req = "manifest.json?current_ver={}".format(self.get_current_version())
        manifest_data = self.get_data(req).decode()
        print(manifest_data)
        manifest = ujson.load(manifest_data)
        gc.collect()
        return manifest
```

In the following folder you will find my code: https://github.com/antec1/Control_Unit

Would be very kind if you could help me to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ujson.loads()` instead of `ujson.load()` to load from a string